# Selecting a row in sorted rich:dataTable

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, richdatatable

I have a rich:dataTable component (RF 4.2.2.Final). I've added the rowclick listener for the table to update a detailed view based on the row selection. Everything was working fine. 
But now I'm trying to get my dataTable to have sortable headers. I follow the RF showcase and find out that the row selection doesn't work properly if the data in the dataTable isn't in natural order - it means in order in which the data is in the list in appQueryBean.
But I'm sure that similar case is fine in RF 3.X

My page:

```
<h:form id="appFormId">
    <div>
        <rich:dataTable id="appListTableId" value="#{appQuery.applicationList}" 
                        var="row" rendered="#{!empty appQuery.applicationList}"
                        rows="50" styleClass="styledTable">
            <a:ajax 
               listener="#{appQuery.actionListener(row.id)}"
                event="rowclick" render=":applistform:appViewId"/> 
            <rich:column style="width:10%">
                <f:facet name="header">#{msg['ID']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.id}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column style="width:20%" sortBy="#{row.code}" 
                  sortOrder="#{applicationSortManager.sortOrder}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <a:commandLink 
                        value="#{msg['APPLICATION.CODE']}" render="appListTableId" 
                        action="#{applicationSortManager.sortByCode}" /></f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.code}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column style="width:50%">
                <f:facet name="header">#{msg['APPLICATION.NAME']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />
            </rich:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:dataScroller id="appBottomScroller" for="appListTableId" 
                        renderIfSinglePage="false" immediate="true" align="left"/>
        </f:facet>    
        </rich:dataTable>
    <div>
</h:form>
```

And ApplicationSortManager:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ApplicationSortManager implements Serializable{

private SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.unsorted;

public void sortByCode(){
    if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ascending)) {
        setSortOrder(SortOrder.descending);
    } else {
        setSortOrder(SortOrder.ascending);
    }
}

/**
 * @return the sortOrder
 */
public SortOrder getSortOrder() {
    return sortOrder;
}

/**
 * @param _sortOrder the sortOrder to set
 */
public void setSortOrder(SortOrder _sortOrder) {
    sortOrder = _sortOrder;
}
}
```

AppQuery is a ViewScoped component with test actionListener implementation:

```
public void actionListener(Long _idApplication){
System.out.println("Action listener - appId: " + _idApplication);
}
```

No matter what is the real order in dataTable - when I click in first row I always get the appId: 1, when second - appId: 2.

How to get the data from row I clicked if the dataTable is sorted?

Comment: Let me forget richfaces table, but keep in mind IDs it generates for elements like myform:mytable:1:keyValue. Create 'onclick' listener on table's td and from event source get needed row element(s) with some smart jquery selector or by pure js. Then by key value of a row call load/show details for a row. Possible?