# richfaces datatable sorting with rowclick event

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces, javabeans, richdatatable

Richfaces datatable returns wrong row for rowclick event after sorting.
For example: test.xhtml

```
<rich:dataTable id="testId" value="#{testBean.names}" var="name">
  <a4j:ajax event="rowclick" listener="#{testBean.selectName(name)}" />
  <rich:column id="name" sortBy="#{name}" sortOrder="#{testBean.nameOrder}">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <a4j:commandLink value="Name" execute="@this" render="testId" action="#{testBean.sortByName}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{name}" />
  </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

TestBean.java

```
public class TestBean {

    private List<String> names;
    private SortOrder nameOrder = SortOrder.unsorted;

    public TestBean() {
        names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("BBBB", "AAAA", "DDDD", "CCCC"));
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void selectName(final String name){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public void sortByName() {
        if (nameOrder.equals(SortOrder.ascending)) {
            setNameOrder(SortOrder.descending);
        } else {
            setNameOrder(SortOrder.ascending);
        }
    }

    public SortOrder getNameOrder() {
        return nameOrder;
    }

    public void setNameOrder(SortOrder nameOrder) {
        this.nameOrder = nameOrder;
    }
}
```

If you run the code above, you will see that whenever you click the first row "AAAA", it will print the console "BBBB".
When I check it on firebug, I notice that the row index doesn't match the cell index.

```
<tr id="**page:testId:0**" class="rf-dt-r rf-dt-fst-r" onclick="RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{"parameters":{"javax.faces.behavior.event":"rowclick","org.richfaces.ajax.component":"page:testId"} ,"sourceId":this} )">
    <td id="**page:testId:1:name**" class="rf-dt-c">AAAA</td>
</tr>
```

Is it a bug in richfaces? Could someone help to fix this problem?

Comment: just noticed that it is the duplicate of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898831/selecting-a-row-in-sorted-richdatatable

Comment: I solved my problem by using client side sorting with jquery. For further details, check : https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter